# Como registrar um estilo externo nos functions do wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, funções

Estou com dificuldade para registrar essa biblioteca de estilo: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani` nas functions do wordpress. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer usar a seguinte [função](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/):

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all')
```

Em `$deps`, você precisa passar um array com estilos já registrados dos quais o estilo atual depende, então você precisa registrar esse css e depois registrar o seu estilo da página e configurar a **fonte** como dependência do estilo da página.

Exemplo:

```
wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani');
wp_enqueue_style('main', '/file/path/', ['fonts']);
```